# Web scraping in Python - how to capture all <a> elements

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using `beautifulsoup4` to scrape data from the lyrics.com website, specifically this link: https://www.lyrics.com/album/1447935.

From this block, I'm trying to extract both `<a>` elements:

```
[<table class="tdata">
    <colgroup>
        <col style="width: 50px;"/>
        <col style="width: 430px;"/>
        <col style="width: 80px;"/>
        <col style="width: 80px;"/>
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Song</th>
            <th>Duration</th>
            <th> </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="tal qx">1</td>
            <td class="tal qx">
                <strong>
                    <a href="/lyric/15183453/Make+You+Feel+My+Love">Make You Feel My Love</a>
                </strong>
            </td>
            <td class="tal qx">3:32</td>
            <td class="tal vam rt"> 
            </td></tr><tr><td class="tal qx">2</td>
            <td class="tal qx">
                <strong>
                    <a href="/lyric/15183454/Painting+Pictures">Painting Pictures</a>
                </strong>
            </td>
            <td class="tal qx">3:33</td>
            <td class="tal vam rt"> </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>]
```

This is my code:

```
url = "http://www.lyrics.com" + album_url
page = r.get(url)
soup = bs(page.content, "html.parser")
songs = [a.get('href') for a in (table.find('a') for table in soup.findAll('table')) if a]
```

However, it's only returning the first `<a>`:

```
['/lyric/15183453/Make+You+Feel+My+Love']
```

What could be wrong?

Edit: Thank you all for the answers! I upvoted but I don't have enough rep for it to show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
songs = [song['href'] for song in soup.select('table a')]
```

Output:

```
['/lyric/15183453/Make+You+Feel+My+Love', '/lyric/15183454/Painting+Pictures']
```

Comment: thanks! chose this answer because it has the links in a list as I needed them

Answer (score 1):

Was able to make it work with:

```
for a in soup.findAll('a'):
    if a.parent.name == 'strong':
        if a.parent.parent.name == 'td':
            print(a["href"])
```

Still not sure why the other method doesn't work, though, since I've used it elsewhere in my program with no issues.

Comment: See my answer for a similar approach to your previous one which is better

Comment: There are cleaner and easier ways to do this using selectors (see my answer) https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class

Answer (score 1):

Other solutions work fine, however I prefer using good old selectors

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests as req
page = req.get('https://www.lyrics.com/album/1447935')
soup = bs(page.content, 'html.parser')
links = soup.select('table.tdata a[href]')
print(links)
```

This will print

```
[<a href="/lyric/15183453/Make+You+Feel+My+Love">Make You Feel My Love</a>, <a href="/lyric/15183454/Painting+Pictures">Painting Pictures</a>]
```

---

If you aren't familiar with selectors, this will grab `table` elements that has the class `tdata` and then collect all the `href` property on the `a` elements

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want `table.findAll` instead of `table.find`.

Comment: When I tried that, I got `AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'get'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?`

Comment: Right, you’ll need to rewrite the rest of it too since findAll is giving you a result set and not a single element. But the reason you were getting just the first tag is because the find function only returns the first match it sees.